# seaborn's coefplot function throwing error

Tags: python, seaborn, data-science

I am trying to use seaborn's `coefplot` function but it is not showing an output. Instead I'm getting an error:

> AttributeError: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'coefplot'.

```
myresultsmyresult .env_corr(env_vars)
def env_corr(self, env_vars, coeff_plot=False, qq_plot=False):
    """
    Determine correlations with environmental/non-discretionary variables
    using a logit regression. Tobit will be implemented when available
    upstream in statsmodels.

    Takes:
        env_vars: A pandas dataframe of environmental variables

    Returns:
        corr_mod: the statsmodels' model instance containing the inputs
                  and results from the logit model.

    Note that there can be no spaces in the variables' names.
    """

    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from statsmodels.regression.linear_model import OLS
    from statsmodels.graphics.gofplots import qqplot
    import seaborn as sns

    env_data = _to_dataframe(env_vars)
    corr_data = env_data.join(self['Efficiency'])
    corr_mod = OLS.from_formula(
        "Efficiency ~ " + " + ".join(env_vars.columns), corr_data)
    corr_res = corr_mod.fit()

    #plot coeffs
    if coeff_plot:
        coefplot("Efficiency ~ " + " + ".join(env_vars.columns),
                 data=corr_data)
        plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')
        plt.title('Regression coefficients and standard errors')

    #plot qq of residuals
    if qq_plot:
        qqplot(corr_res.resid, line='s')
        plt.title('Distribution of residuals')

    print(corr_res.summary())

    return corr_res
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you share your code please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that seaborn's coefplot function has been officially deprecated in version 0.8.0 ( July 2017)

Please refer to the link below:

https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew.html

Thanks!

Comment: correct. Here the additional link where is stated the final removal in v0.9 https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/commit/cbcf7a556752409681725bdebb8bad27c68abf6c#diff-bbd4a31e4848d0ab1d2c8ae2d0aaa2f4